# current transformer behaving like voltage transformer

Tags: current, transformer

I wrapped wire around a steel core, and then i put a cable that carries around 10A through the center. This should be a current transformer and should behave like a constant current source. The bigger the load in the secondary the bigger the voltage drop should be (with the current staying constant). And the more the turns of the secondary the less the current should be. But that is not what happened.

As i put bigger resistors in the secondary the current dropped along with the voltage drop. As i wrapped more turns around the core, there was a bigger current and a bigger voltage drop in the secondary.

This behavior is similar to a voltage transformer, isn't it? What is happening?

Comment: What do you think the differences between a "voltage transformer" and a "current transformer" are? Last I checked, there were generally only transformers.

Comment: Also, where would the additional power going into the load on the secondary come from? If the secondary current stays the same, and the voltage increases, that's also an increase in power. Unless you're putting in a correspondingly larger amount of power, of *course* the secondary current is going to drop.

Comment: @Conner the OP says 'should behave like a constant current source' which is IMO correct. The extra power would come from an increased voltage drop over the primary.

Comment: Based on what i've read all over the internet, in a current transformer current in the primary is not controlled by the secondary load, where in a voltage transformer that is what happens. In a CT, voltage drop in the primary winding (usually only 1, the cable that is passing through the core) is very small, and is stepped up in the secondary. They also say that you should never open circuit a CT, or put a really big resistor because then a big voltage drop would appear in the primary and that would be stepped up based on the turns on the secondary. None of this behavior showed up in my case.

Comment: "Current transformer" and "Voltage transformer" are - in the end - just names. If you wrap wire around a metal core, you get a transformer. If your circuit goes "AC source -> Transformer -> Load" with nothing in there to control things, I would absolutely expect current to change with changing loads.

Comment: @medivh Yes, but applying general transformer theory, it still doesn't make sense. Since you don't control the primary current by the secondary load as you do in a VT, primary current is constant. As you increase the secondary load, the reflected or referred resistance in the primary rises too. And as you have more turns on the secondary its a step up transformer. Voltage will rise in the secondary too. All over the internet I read that a CT acts like a constant current source. But it seems that it doesn't, or I did something wrong.

Comment: You absolutely control primary current by changing the load. If you doubt this, try drawing out an idealized load-free circuit (That is: Ideal AC source, ideal transformer, open connection on the secondary side) and calculate the primary-side current. Then add a load to the secondary side and recalculate. EDIT: You said "You don't... ...as you do in a VT" where I assume you mean Voltage Transformer. If you want to understand what is happening, you need to get the idea of "voltage transformer" out of your head. There is no VT, there is no CT, there are only transformers. VT and CT are usenames.

Comment: @medivh A CT has minimal insertion loss. What you say is about a VT. In a CT no matter what you do on the secondary, the primary, connected in series with the load you are measuring current for, will not be affected. For example a current transformer measuring the current of a microwave oven will not reduce the current it is drawing from the mains. So primary current is constant. You can search google for that.

Comment: "You can search google for that." Or I could be an electronics engineer. One or the other. EDIT: That was dismissive and I apologize. Rather, let me ask you a question: Am I correct in understanding that this is what you're reffering to: http://openbookproject.net/electricCircuits/AC/02156.png

Comment: Sorry if it offended you, I meant it is all over the internet, not something I made up. Yes this is what i am reffering to. Also this [link](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3b/Stromwandler_Zeichnung.svg/160px-Stromwandler_Zeichnung.svg.png)

Comment: You did not offend, I am just tired. If you take the circuit I showed, remove the (A) and add in a load, it acts as a voltage transformer. EDIT: Even without a load, it is still a voltage transformer, because all transformers are voltage transformers. And it is still a current transfomer, because all transformers are current transformers.

Comment: In a power transformer, if load is disconnected, there will be only magnetizing current. The primary of pt takes current from the source proportional to the load connected. But in case of CT, the primary is connected in series with powerline. So current through its primary is nothing but the current that flows through that power line. The primary current of the CT, hence does not depend upon whether the load or burden is connected to the secondary or not or what is the impedance value of burden.
from [link](http://bit.ly/14xwm3K)
So adding a load will not affect it the same way as a VT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The differences between a voltage transformer and a current transformer are only in the construction. The theory is the same for both.

The secondary current in a (current) transformer is *not* constant, regardless of load. The secondary current is only proportional to the primary current with the secondary short-circuited. With the secondary open-circuit, the secondary voltage is proportional to the *rate-of-change* of the primary current, and might be very large if the primary current changes rapidly.

With a resistive load, the output voltage will depend on both the primary current and it's rate-of-change. Manufacturers of current transformers therefore quote a maximum load resistance (or a maximum secondary voltage) for which the transformer's primary/secondary current ratio will remain in specification.

Here is a Bode plot (on logarithmic axes) of an ideal current transformer. As you would expect, at dc there is no output. Ls represents the secondary inductance, and RL is the resistance in the secondary circuit, ie the sum of the secondary resistance and the load resistance.

[image: Bode plot of ideal current transformer]

If we start with the black line as our transfer function, and our operating frequency is indicated by the blue line, we get the expected 1/N current ratio. If we increase the load resistance RL enough (the red line), our blue line now intersects the transfer function at a lower current ratio. So we require \$R_L<2\pi fL_S\$ for normal operation.

Comment: The primary winding is usually a very low impedance and therefore treated as a "brute force" constant current source. Faraday's law of ampere-turn balance states that the number of turns
in the primary winding times the primary current must equal the number of turns in the secondary winding times the secondary current.
since the primary is a constant current source, the secondary becomes a constant current source proportional only to the turns
ratio. from [link](http://www.digikey.com/Web%20Export/Supplier%20Content/CRMagnetics_582/PDF/cr-magnetics-pi-calculating-ratio-errors.pdf?redirected=1)

Comment: I can quote a lot of links and discussions saying the same as above. That is why they also say never to open circuit a CT, as it tries to keep the current constant in the secondary (which will need an infinite voltage since there is infinite resistance)

Comment: That is only true if the secondary is short circuit. With an open-circuit secondary, the secondary voltage is given by \$V_S = M\dfrac{\mathrm dI_p}{\mathrm dt}\$ - where M is the mutual inductance - that's also Faraday's law.

Comment: Isn't the secondary resistance referred to the primary with R2'=TurnsRatio^2*R2 ? Hence a really big resistance and voltage drop on the primary?

Comment: You need to consider the primary inductance too (albeit low). With an open circuit secondary, the primary appears as the primary inductance only (which presents a finite impedance at a finite frequency, and an open-circuit at infinite frequency). With the secondary short-circuit, the primary presents a short-circuit also (ideally).

Comment: So with an appliance that draws 8A at 220VAC, and measuring the current in the cable with a CT, as you increase the secondary resistance what should happen in your opinion? An increase or decrease in sec. current?

Comment: @1p2r3k4t this is moving away from your problem - have you checked the core is laminated?

Comment: It is either laminated or ferrite, but I also used a solid steel core and got the same results.

Comment: @MikeJ-UK from [link](http://electricalnotes.wordpress.com/2011/04/16/current-transformer/)
"When a CT secondary circuit is closed, current flows through it, which is an exact proportion of the primary current, regardless of the resistance of the burden. In the CT have a ratio of 1OOO/5A and to have 1OOOA flowing in the primary is carrying exactly 5A." What do you have to say about this?

Comment: @1p2r3k4t - From your link :- `A current transformer is defined as “as an instrument transformer in which the secondary current is substantially proportional to the primary current (under normal conditions of operation)`. Note the words 'substantially' and 'normal'. The idea that the secondary current is independent of burden is just plain wrong.

Comment: @MikeJ-UK Do you agree that the sec current is in a quite good degree proportional to prim current, and that as you increase the secondary burden the accuracy of the CT or the sec current will fall but will still be quite proportional to the prim current. It's just that the error increases, right?

Comment: @1p2r3k4t - Yes, I agree. With a constant primary current, as you increase the secondary load resistance the secondary voltage evetually stops increasing and the secondary current will start falling, but they are still proportional to primary current. As the load approaches infinity, the secondary current falls to zero and the secondary voltage reaches a maximum - hence your observation of a voltage transformer effect. Neglecting saturation effects, capacitance and poor magnetic coupling, the effect starts when \$R_L=2\pi fL_S\$

Comment: @MikeJ-UK Thank you. Where does that equation come from?

Comment: @1p2r3k4t - I've added some explanation to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

> I wrapped wire around a steel core

Unfortunately the steel core you used will act as a shorted turn. You are wrapping your wire around a shorted turn and you expect something sensible to come out - this won't happen.

CTs are just like any other transformer - the iron/steel core should be laminated to reduce induced currents in them. The laminations isolate the induced currents and greatly reduce their influence: -

[image]

Note the laminations in the above diagram - the core is made from multiple sheets of silicon steel and each sheet is insulated from each other.

Ferrites are OK because the "iron" is basically dust and surrounding each particle is an insulator - this is lamination technology on a microscopic level.

**EDIT** I'm editing this to explain why only a finite voltage will be produced by a current transformer. CTs don't behave to some "other" theory - they follow transformer theory and this theory is equipped to deal with CTs. The equivalent circuit is: -

[image]

On a normal VT the magnetizing current (see red arrow) is very small because the magnetizing inductance is very large and is typically greater than 10H (generalization). this means it only draws a few milli-amps when the full AC voltage is applied to it.

CTs, on the other hand have a magnetizing inductance that is very small, in the order of micro-henries or a few milli-henries because the primary winding is a single turn. This single turn carries the load current that we wish to measure.

In the middle of the diagram of the transformer equivalent circuit is a "perfect" transformer with a turns ratio of secondary turns divided by primary turns. Thus the voltage across the magnetizing inductance is applied, via the turns ratio to the secondary terminals. On a CT this "input" voltage is a few milli-volts and therefore if the secondary has 300 turns, it will produce 600mV based on an input of 2mV across the magnetizing inductance,

We can neglect leakage inductances to make the "visualization" easier and we end up with this: -

[image]

Anything else would not be the laws of physics. You do not get infinite output voltage because there isn't infinite turns ratio. Just because the primary current appears to be going into the "perfect" transformer, look again.... it's actually magnetizing the core and this only produces a few milli volts which is magnified by the turns ratio. It's a transformer just like voltage transformers and has limitations.

Comment: the wire was regular plastic insulated wire you use in electronics projects

Comment: @1p2r3k4t I'm not talking about the wire; I'm talking about the steel core - any transformer has to substantially reduce eddy currents being induced in the core - ferrites or laminations are used. A solid steel core is acting as a shorted turn.

Comment: Thanks, i misunderstood what you said. But if you look here [link](http://scholarcommons.sc.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1004&context=elct_facpub) you will see that they also got VT behavior out of their CT

Comment: @1p2r3k4t are they using laminates?

Comment: Yes, they used a few flexible foils of
mu-metal stacked up to form a laminated core. (edit: The core i used was a toroidal core. Are these laminated inside?)

Comment: @1p2r3k4t you said the core was steel, you did not say it was laminated steel. I do not know if your toroidal core is laminated or not (how could I?). Which section of the document (linked to) says they cad problems with their CT behaving like a VT?

Comment: On page 1255, tables II & III you can see that while they increased the sec. load resistance power and current were reduced. Where as if a CT behaves like a constant current source, you increase the resistance and current should remain the same, and power dissipated should rise, shouldn't it? Moreover, on Figure 13 they have modeled their CT as a voltage source not a cuurent source.

Comment: @1p2r3k4t table II and III are when they use diodes to try and create a dc power source and table II/III are simulated results based on a voltage source therefore irrelevant. This problem, as far as I am concerned boils down to whether you have used laminates and not what a simulation by the University of South Carolina appears to indicate.

Comment: They just rectify the ac, it shouldn't matter. You can also see on page 1253, that they measure ac voltage on the sec. directly with a voltmeter, with no load. The voltmeter has a big internal resistance thus they should get really big voltage. But they don't. Every behavior is not what it should be, according to CT theory.

Comment: @1p2r3k4t And which theory is this? CT theory? A CT is one use of a VT - a CT still has an input voltage (maybe a couple of mV), a turns ratio and an open circuit output voltage. They use about 300 turns so what output would you get open circuit? I'd say about 500mV. Check your core and be more realistic.

Comment: How do you explain that by increasing the secondary turns they get higher sec. current (due to higher sec. voltage)? I2=I1*N1/N2 I1 is constant, N1=1 and N2 is increasing, so I2 should decrease (I had this behavior in the core i used too)

Comment: @1p2r3k4t maybe this better overcomes the diodes forward voltage drop